# assign value to pointer to char array in one func, use it in another

Tags: c

I have a function that declares an array of chars and then assigns a value to it and then the decayed pointer is passed to another func like this pseudo c code, so that if I do `printf("country %s," country)` inside `anotherfunc` it gives me "GERMANY"

```
void somefunc()
{
...
char *country = NULL;
country = "GERMANY"
...

anotherfunc(country); //printf("country %s," country)` == GERMANY
}
```

How do I move the call to anotherfunc outside of somefunc and still be able to pass the country char array? Right now, `printf("country %s," country)` is giving me `(null)`

```
char *country = NULL; // declare country outside both somefunc and anotherfunc

somefunc(country); //"GERMANY" is assigned inside somefunc

//if I do `printf("country %s," country)` it is `(null)`
//so "GERMANY" is not available inside another func

anotherfunc(country);
```

Comment: You can do what's in the duplicate, or simply modify `somefunc` to return a pointer.

Comment: Welcome to the minimalist world of C programming ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void somefunc(char **pcountry) {
  *pcountry = "GERMANY";
}
```

and call it

```
somefunc(&country);
```

Comment: for completeness, then what do I pass to anotherfunc and please show the call of somefunc, like this `somefunc(&country)`?

Comment: That's what I did but it's still null, do I declare it `char *country` or `char **country`?

Comment: `char *country`.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. I'll accept your answer in 34 seconds once SO lets me.

Comment: I'm getting a warning from the compiler using the code from your answer-- `incompatible pointer types passing `char ***` to parameter of type 'char **'` I declare country like this: `char **country = NULL;`  and then pass it  `somefunc(&country) anotherfunc(&country)`.  The signature of `anotherfunc` and `somefunc` are like this `somefunc( char**country)`   Note, I'll keep your answer as accepted for now, because I assume I'm doing something wrong ! Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you are doing something wrong.

Comment: ok, thank you, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong, or is it not clear from my comment? or is it outside the scope of the question?

Comment: I posted another question with a link to sample code regarding this error. I don't think I'm doing something wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654861/compiler-recommendation-leads-to-seg-fault